# React useEffect dependencies invalidation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently working on a react project and I ran into the need of manually triggering an useEffect. For that, I am using an extra dependency, a "valid" flag, which if true will also trigger a fetch. The thing is, the fetch also has parameters that it depends on, so now my effect depends on [page, limit, title, valid]. The problem with this is that I cannot simply let it this way, because then I wouldn't know when I should refetch. What would be a good solution to allow refetch on parameter changes but also when manually changing the "valid" param? For now, I am doing the following:

```js
export function useJobOpenings(page: number, limit: number, title: string): UseJobOpeningsResponse {
    const [jobOpenings, setJobOpenings] = useState<JobOpeningDTO[]>([]);
    const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<unknown>();
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setValid(false);
    }, [limit, page, title]);

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    useEffect(fetchJobOpenings, [valid]);

    return { jobOpenings, fetching, error, invalidate: (): void => setValid(false) };

    function fetchJobOpenings(): (() => void) | void {
        if (valid) return;
        let mounted = true;

        asyncFetch();

        return (): void => {
            mounted = false;
        };

        async function asyncFetch(): Promise<void> {
            setFetching(true);
            try {
                const _jobOpenings = await getAllJobOpenings({ title, page, limit });
                if (!mounted) return;

                setJobOpenings(_jobOpenings.data);
                setFetching(false);
                setValid(true);
            } catch (err) {
                if (!mounted) return;
                setError(err);
                setFetching(false);
                setValid(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it seems really counterintuitive to update the "valid" flag based on the other dependencies and then use only that flag in the effect that actually does the fetching, since it also triggers the exhaustive deps elsint rule, even though it seems pretty obvious, hopefully it is correct as well, that the valid flag already depends on the 3 other parameters.

Comment: Are you saying you want an effect to trigger when one of `page, limit, title` update, or when `valid` updates?

Comment: I want it to trigger on both, either when page, limit, title changes or when manually updating it via invalidate().

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? Is there an issue with using `[page, limit, title, valid]` as the dependency array?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, if valid is always set to true then the first "if" in the effect would always return without fetching. If i remove that check, then I will always get 2 fetches, since the effect will run once when valid is set to false manually and again when it will be set back to true in the effect. I could maybe instead of thinking of valid either as "valid" or "invalid" to take any change to it as invalidating. Then I could use a single array with all of them as deps, and invalidate will then be "() => setValid((old) => !old)". It would be weird to read though, and kinda bad naming.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Sorry for asking this but sometimes talking to somebody helps it and I had nobody to talk this over with :). So it would work but instead of checking if valid is actually true I shouldn't care about its value but use it only for the fact that it can change. Should think of a better name probably instead of "valid"

Comment: So is it actually the dependency when any of `page, limit, title` update, or when `valid` updates and is true?

Comment: It should depend on all of them, it's just that it shouldn't matter if valid is true or not.

Comment: Ah, so like an additional "forceFetch" state that you toggle or update purely to trigger the effect and refetch. Sounds good.

Comment: Exactly, that's it. I never had to implement something of the sort and I was unsure how to tackle it, had nobody to sanity check it with though. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what purpose does your code serve, but I've had a similar use case when I wanted to refetch data once I knew it was changed.
Here is a solution I came up with. I know it's written in a different manner than your code it, but hope it helps.

It's a general purpose component used to fetch data from an endpoint, which url and data you specify as arguments.

```
export const Resource = ({ path, data, children, ...props }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState([]);
    const [refreshVar, setRefreshVar] = useState(false);

    const refresh = () => {
        setRefreshVar(v => !v)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let func = data ? axios.post : axios.get;
        func(path, data)
            .then(res => {
                setPayload(res.data)
                setLoading(false)
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }, [path, refreshVar, data]);

    return children({ loading, payload, refresh, ...props });
};
```

Then you have a component which you can use this way:

```
<Resource path={api.yourEndpoint}>
    {({ payload, loading, refresh }) => {
        if (!loading && payload.length === 0) {
            return <EmptyComponent />;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                {payload.map((record, index) => (
                    <div>{record.value}</div>
                ))}

               <button onClick={refresh}>
                   Refetch Data
               </button>
            </div>
        );
    }}
</Resource>
```

From this point you could create a component instead of the sample div passing down the arguments, validating the fetched data inside and calling the refresh function if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, the idea would be to not count on valid for the "true" value but instead to care only about the fact that it can change.

```js
export function useJobOpenings(page: number, limit: number, title: string): UseJobOpeningsResponse {
    const [jobOpenings, setJobOpenings] = useState<JobOpeningDTO[]>([]);
    const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<unknown>();
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

    useEffect(fetchJobOpenings, [limit, page, title, valid]);

    return { jobOpenings, fetching, error, invalidate: (): void => setValid((old) => !old) };

    function fetchJobOpenings(): (() => void) | void {
        let mounted = true;

        asyncFetch();

        return (): void => {
            mounted = false;
        };

        async function asyncFetch(): Promise<void> {
            setFetching(true);
            try {
                const _jobOpenings = await getAllJobOpenings({ title, page, limit });
                if (!mounted) return;

                setJobOpenings(_jobOpenings.data);
                setFetching(false);
            } catch (err) {
                if (!mounted) return;
                setError(err);
                setFetching(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that inside the effect there's no check whether valid is true or false, nor does it set it to any value, since the only thing that matters is the fact that the value can change and trigger the effect.